# Get total number of each day between two date in php

Tags: php, intervals, datediff, days

If I give 2 dates, I need results as follow -

```
SUNDAY = 3 TIMES
MONDAY = 3 TIMES
TUESDAY = 4 TIMES
WEDNESDAY = 4 TIMES
THURSDAY = 4 TIMES
FRIDAY  = 4 TIMES
SATRUDAY = 4 TIMES
```

I am confused if this can be done via any function in mysql or I have to do it from php.
I tried with various ways in mysql but could not get any success. I am trying it in php but the codes is somewhat getting lengthy.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. We do not write code for you for free.

Comment: also your problem is not explained at all

Comment: Please refer to [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) for information on how to better post a question.  I have no idea what it is you want.

Comment: I appology for not following rules while posting questions..and thank you so much for the advice. I will surely take these into considerations while posting questions. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
define('ONE_WEEK', 604800); // 7 * 24 * 60 * 60

function number_of_days($day, $start, $end)
{
    $w = array(date('w', $start), date('w', $end));

    return floor( ( $end - $start ) / ONE_WEEK ) + ( $w[0] > $w[1] ? $w[0] <= $day || $day <= $w[1] : $w[0] <= $day && $day <= $w[1] );
}

//$start = $end = time();

echo number_of_days(0, $start, $end); // SUNDAY
echo number_of_days(1, $start, $end); // MONDAY
echo number_of_days(2, $start, $end); // TUESDAY
echo number_of_days(3, $start, $end); // WEDNESDAY
echo number_of_days(4, $start, $end); // THURSDAY
echo number_of_days(5, $start, $end); // FRIDAY
echo number_of_days(6, $start, $end); // SATURDAY
?>
```